# How to send props to components via Link / Routes from react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Like the title says, how to send data to props from one component to another via Link. This is how am I doing it now, but because of this the url in the browser gets too big, and I feel like that is not the way you do this, but here is how I did it:

I have one component called Routes.js where I store all my routes like this:

```
    {
    path: "/edit/:id/:name/:email/:status/:gender/:title/:method",
    component: ActionsPage,
    exact: true,
  },
```

As you can see this path gets too large, as these `:name` and etc. are actually my parameters and in the component that I need these props I have put this:

```
let { id, name, email, status, gender, title, method } = useParams();
```

Is there any other way to send props for example let's use this ActionsPage.js component that I use, can I somehow send these props differently, or to be precise to send them normally like when you send them without using Link?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass some props in `Link` from `react-router`.

In the following example, `toPathWithProps` stores both the destination `pathname` and the `props` you'd like to pass. Here we're passing `param1` as `props`.

```
// your link creation
const toPathwithProps = { 
  pathname: "/page", 
  param1: "Par1" 
};

// link to the "location"
<Link to={toPathwithProps}> </Link>
```

`param1` will be found in the `props` of the destination component. But remember, should the user navigate to `/page` without using the `Link` tag, no `props` will be passed.

So lets say the "menu" component redirects to the "edit" page (the page you're mentioning in your question). To do this, all you have to do is add a `Link` tag in your "menu" component. Example:

```
    <Link to={
      pathname: "/edit", 
      user: {id:props.id,name:props.name,email:props.email}}>
      Edit Profile </Link>
```

So the user just clicks on the `Link` and is taken to the "edit" page. The "edit" component will be able to access the `user`'s info in its props. Because we passed them as `params` in the `Link`.

Now you don't have to use the full path `/edit/:id/:name/:email/:status/:gender/:title/:method`
you can use just `/edit`

Comment: I'm not sure this works for my component. Where do I create this, and what do I do with my Route.js component, do I change the path there as well or not, can you please explain?

Comment: instead of the full path: "/edit/:id/:name/:email/:status/:gender/:title/:method" you can simply use path: "/edit". And pass the parameters (id,name,email, etc...) via a link tag. Let me edit my answer